# I have two tables one after another. First one is appearing, second is not

Tags: longtable, ieeetran, threeparttable

```
\begin{table*}[!htb]
    \small
    \centering
    \caption{Performance comparison}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Datasets}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Methods} \\ \cline{3-5} 
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Yang et al. \cite{byang}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ferrara et al. \cite{pmcc}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Proposed method\end{tabular}}} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FV02\end{tabular}} 
        & DB1 & - & 0 & 0 \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & DB2 & 5.72 & 6.02 & 1.13 \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & DB3 & - & 12.43 & 13.39 \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & DB4 & - & 37 & 32 \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FV06\end{tabular} 
        & DB2 & - & 0.03  & 0.09 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\normalsize
\begin{table*}[!htb]
    \small
    \centering
    \caption{Performance comparison}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Datasets}} & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Methods} \\ \cline{3-11} 
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ahmad \\ et al. \cite{pairp}\end{tabular}}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Wang\\ et al. \cite{ditom}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Lee\\ et al. \\ \cite{lmi}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Wong\\ et al. \cite{mlc}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Yang \\ et al. \cite{byang}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Boult \\ et al. \cite{boult}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ferrara\\ et al. \cite{pmcc}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ferrara \\ et al. \cite{2pmcc}\end{tabular}}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Proposed \\ method\end{tabular}}} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FV\\ 02\end{tabular}} 
        & DB1 & 91  & 13.5  & 13.4 & 14.69  & -    & 12.1 & 11.88 & 13.3 & 11.59 \\ \cline{2-11} 
        & DB2 & 16  & 14    & -   & 15.03  & 14.53 & 11.2 & 0.99 & 1.8 & 1.03 \\ \cline{2-11} 
        & DB3 & 27 & 7.5  & -   & -     & -    &  -  & 5.24 & 7.8 & 4.02 \\ \cline{2-11} 
        & DB4 & -  & -    & -   & -     & -    &  -  & 4.84 & 6.6 & 3.74 \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FV\\ 04\end{tabular} 
        & DB1 & - & - & - & 10.36 & -  & - & - & 6.3 & 4.38 \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FV\\ 06\end{tabular} 
        & DB2 & - & - & - & - & - & -  & 0.17 & 0.3 & 0.19 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tablenotes}\small
        \item $``-"$ indicates that the author(s) have not reported the results or results are reported for partial dataset, in their work.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: I am using ieeetran latex class

Comment: If I use the `IEEEtran` document class with the class option `twocolumn` and load the `multirow` and `threeparttable` packages, I actually have no problem compiling the test document, i.e., both `table`s show up. Please provide a compilable example that generates the problem behavior you need to fix.

Comment: Is the second `table` maybe showing up on a later page?

Comment: @Mico First one is appearing...second one is not.. I dont know why even after compiling successfully

Comment: Does the second `table` maybe show up at the very end of the document? Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't provided standalone, compilable code that generates the problem you're looking to fix, it's not possible to diagnose with any kind of certainty what's going on. My hunch is that the `[htb!]` specifiers are causing the problem. In a `twocolumn` document they're redundant anyway; I'd omit them.

Alternatively, you could simply place both `tabular` environments and their associated captions in *one* `table*` environment, using a `\bigskip` directive to separate the material.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % <-- for a slightly more open 'look'
\centering
% \small %% not needed, as it's automatic with the IEEEtran document class

\caption{Performance comparison} \label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Datasets}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Methods} \\ 
\cline{3-5}  
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} 
& Yang et~al.\ \cite{byang}
& Ferrara et~al.\ \cite{pmcc} 
& Proposed method \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FV02\end{tabular}} 
& DB1 & -- & 0 & 0 \\ \cline{2-5} 
& DB2 & 5.72 & 6.02 & 1.13 \\ \cline{2-5} 
& DB3 & -- & 12.43 & 13.39 \\ \cline{2-5} 
& DB4 & -- & 37 & 32 \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FV06\end{tabular} 
& DB2 & -- & 0.03  & 0.09 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}  

\bigskip

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Performance comparison}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|*{11}{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Datasets}} 
& \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Methods} \\ 
\cline{3-11} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ahmad \\ et~al.\ \cite{pairp}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Wang\\ et~al.\ \cite{ditom}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Lee\\ et~al.\ \cite{lmi}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Wong\\ et~al.\ \cite{mlc}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Yang \\ et~al.\ \cite{byang}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Boult \\ et~al.\ \cite{boult}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ferrara\\ et~al.\ \cite{pmcc}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ferrara \\ et~al.\ \cite{2pmcc}\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Proposed \\ method\end{tabular}}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{FV02} 
& DB1 & 91  & 13.5  & 13.4 & 14.69  & -- & 12.1 & 11.88 & 13.3 & 11.59 \\ \cline{2-11} 
& DB2 & 16  & 14& -- & 15.03  & 14.53 & 11.2 & 0.99 & 1.8 & 1.03 \\ \cline{2-11} 
& DB3 & 27 & 7.5 & -- & -- & -- & -- & 5.24 & 7.8 & 4.02 \\ \cline{2-11} 
& DB4 & -- & -- & --  & -- & -- & -- & 4.84 & 6.6 & 3.74 \\ \hline
FV04 & DB1 & -- & -- & -- & 10.36 & -- & -- & --   & 6.3 & 4.38 \\ \hline
FV06 & DB2 & -- & -- & -- & --    & -- & -- & 0.17 & 0.3 & 0.19 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item ``--" indicates that the author(s) have not reported the results or that results are reported for partial dataset in their work.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```